# How memory is allocated for struct type in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct like

```
struct Student
{
    bool isActive;
};
```

Now if I see the output of the size of this struct as following:

```
Student student;
cout << sizeof(student);
```

then it shows 1, which is fine as bool is 1 byte in size. For

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
};
```

output is 4, which is fine again as string is 4 bytes in size.
But for the following:

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    bool isActive;
};
```

my expectation for `sizeof(student)` was 4 + 1 = 5, however the output shows 8. Why is that so?

Comment: See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member).

Answer (score 3):

Data types have natural alignments, in the case you give that alignment is 4 so the total size is 8. The natural alignment is required for some processors and makes accesses much faster on all architectures. The alignment is generally equal to the largest member of a struct or union, although there are sometimes reasons to override this and make it even larger (data types used with Intel SSE instructions for example).